# TokenError: Code was already redeemed and TokenError: Bad Request - Passport Google OAuth 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, oauth-2.0, google-plus-signin

I have a pretty basic passport setup as you can see below. Every once in a while I get two different errors. `TokenError: Code was already redeemed` and `TokenError: Bad Request` for reasons I cannot seem to find.

I've looked around a lot (1 week) for possible solutions but am yet to find one which works.

Do you see anything wrong with the current code?

```
app.get('/auth/google', redirect, passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);
```

**Here are the two errors:**

```
TokenError: Bad Request 
  at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:320:12) 
  at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:367:16) 
  at /app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45 
  at /app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18 
  at passBackControl (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:123:9) 
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7) 
  at emitNone (events.js:85:20) 
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7) 
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12) 
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11) 
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)



TokenError: Code was already redeemed. 
      at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:320:12) 
      at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:367:16) 
      at /app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45 
      at /app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18 
      at passBackControl (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:123:9) 
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7) 
      at emitNone (events.js:85:20) 
      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7) 
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12) 
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11) 
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```